# Can we set value of Developer Setting 'do not keep activities' through code?

Tags: android

Can we set the value of the Developer Setting 'do not keep activities' through code?

We can get its value by

```
Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

However, I want to set the checkbox value in "settings > system > Developer Options > Apps >> Do Not Keep Activities" through code.

Comment: *Hi i can set flag ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES value through* `Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);` But even after defining Security permissions in the Manifest file, log is still saying have to import these. how to make sure the application runs fine in local.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below :

```
  Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ALWAYS_FINISH_ACTIVITIES, 0);
```

and also take permission these two permission also
Write_setting
Set_activity_finish